# Tomcat cannot reach via port 8443 SSL

Tags: java, nginx, ssl, tomcat

I have setup my webapp on ec2, I use nginx to serve static contents and added SSL using letsencrypt (working fine), and my backend is also hosted in the same server using tomcat, I converted *.pem files which are generated by letsencrypt to .jks file to provide the SSL for tomcat (8443), but the 8443 port in not connecting (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET). 8080 is working fine (NO SSL).

Here is my server.xml entry for

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/conf/bb.co.uk.jks"
        keystorePass="password"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I checked logs but cannot find any error,

```
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 18 2023 09:25:13 UTC
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.438 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.72.0
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.15.0-1011-aws
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu122.04
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Private Build
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.439 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.452 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.457 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.865 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
28-Feb-2023 20:41:19.910 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
28-Feb-2023 20:41:20.357 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.logCertificate Connector [https-jsse-nio-8443], TLS virtual host [_default_], certificate type [UNDEFINED] configured from [/opt/tomcat/conf/bb.co.uk.jks] using alias [tomcat] and with trust store [null]
28-Feb-2023 20:41:20.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1128] milliseconds
28-Feb-2023 20:41:20.420 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
28-Feb-2023 20:41:20.420 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.72]
28-Feb-2023 20:41:20.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/bb.war]
28-Feb-2023 20:41:23.582 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
```

I also tried the SSL cfg as follows, but same issue

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
                     certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem"/>
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I access static content via https://bb.co.uk and I want to access the backend via https://bb.co.uk:8443.

Comment: What is in the keystore `bb.co.uk.jks`? Use `keystore -list [file]`.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the issue, I configured them correctly. I had to wait around 6 hours to apply the changes.